# concatenate @ to string in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a rails form that takes in a slack username. In my view it concatenates a "@" to it as follows:

```
<div class="col-md-5ths col-xs-6"><h3>Slack </h3><h2> <%= "@#{@user.slack}"%></h2></div>
```

How would I have the edit form append the "@" so the user know's it's there?

Current form

```
<%= f.label :slack, "Slack username" %>
<%= f.text_field :slack, :maxlength => 30, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Comment: I normally put prefixed assumptions _before_ the field itself. e.g. `@<%= f.text_field ...`

Comment: @sjagr got it. is there a way to do it in the text field (kinda like a permanent placeholder)?

Comment: You could wrap the `text_field` helper in a new (self created) `at_text_field` view helper.

Answer (score 3):

`placeholder` disappears by **design**, I see that you're using Bootstrap, one way you could handle it is using `input-group-addon` to prepend or append elements

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

[image]

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups